# A simple tutorial on how to call a WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have created a simple WCF by following several tutorials.  I have modified my web.config file to add the endpoint (whatever that is).  I added a ServiceReference to my solution...  Now I just want to call the darn thing to see if it works...

I found this code when I viewed the service in the browser:

```
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

    // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

    // Always close the client.
    client.Close();
```

But when I plug it into my default.aspx on my website I get errors:

The type or namespacen anme 'ServiceClient' could not be found.  All I want to do is call it to see how I reference the method (with parameters) and how it returns the data.  I just need a jumping point to start working with WCF.

Please help.

**Answered!**

SnOrfus - His answer did the trick.  As soon as I added the ServiceReference to the project then when I hovered over the client variable it prompted me to add ServiceReference name (which was ServiceReference1).

I was then able to call my method and display the results.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a WCF _end point_, or WCF _service_, not just a "WCF".

Comment: I did say I was new at this right?  Sorry...  Thanks for the correction.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have the relevant `using` clause for the ServiceClient? If not, try pressing Ctrl-.  (that's a full stop) when the cursor is on the ServiceClient text, and let Visual Studio resolve the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your service interface called and what namespace did you give it when you added it? For instance, if you defined it thusly:

```
[OperationContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationMethod]
    void MyServiceMethod();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
}
```

if you imported it using the *Add Service Reference* dialog and gave it a namespace of JeffService... it would look like:

```
var client = new JeffService.MyServiceClient();
client.MyServiceMethod();
client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added the Service Reference, what namespace did you type in ?

Normally, to access it via code you'd just have to use code that looks like this:

```
NameSpace.ClientName client = new NameSpace.ClientName();
```